# Angular 5- Package.json-lock

Tags: angular5

1. Can someone explain me exactly why is this package.json-lock file is
   used in our project?
2. How it is Used?
3. If any third party Component is installed in my project after npm
   install will it affect this file as well?

Answer (score 1):

so being straight on point I hope you know what package.JSON files do and what is the use of it.

in short package.JSON files give you the information of your project starting from name to npm dependencies of your project and This file is used to give information to npm that allows it to identify the project as well as handle the project's dependencies.

coming to package.json-lock file

package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where you installed any node modules package to your project or npm modifies either the node_modules folder, or you change something in your package.json file.

so for example you install one third party module using npm install.
and added module version in package.json file. the same will be also generated in package-lock.json.

file structure of package-lock.json is typically same as package.json file
where there is lot more information in dependencies

so dependencies is a mapping of package name to dependency object. Dependency objects have the following properties have a look [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)

coming to your questions

1) Can someone explain me exactly why is this package.json-lock file is used in our project?

ans) It stores an exact, versioned dependency information in structure tree rather than using starred versioning like package.json itself (e.g. 1.0.*). This means you can guarantee the dependencies for other developers or prod releases, etc. It also has a mechanism to lock the tree but generally will regenerate if package.json changes or you installed any new module.

2) How it is Used?

ans) it locks in the versions of the full dependency tree. This allows you to guarantee your dependency tree for other developers or for releases whilst still allowing testing of new dependency versions (direct or indirect) using your standard package.json.

3)If any third party Component is installed in my project after npm install will it affect this file as well?

ans)The package-lock.json file is being updated every single time you call npm install since NPM 5.1. (change in github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866, example in github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979) It therefore can no longer be used to set the same versions for all developers, unless you specify exact versions like 1.2.3 instead of 1.2.* in your package.json file.